# More than 2 Models in a ModelView with a twist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I have been looking at C# MVC for a while now and really getting in to it. I have come across how to pass 2 or more Domain Models in to a View but what i need to ask is security. I have read about Over Posting and that is can be stopped with Binding inclusions and exclusions but how does this effect a ViewModel with 2 or more Model inside it. Is there still the possibility of hidden fields in the HTML that resolve to the Domain Models and are they editable.

I have been looking to make ViewModels where i give it certain things i want the user to edit but it just seems over complicated, so is there a better and easier way of doing this.

```
public TicketViewModel {
    private Ticket _ticket;

    public TicketViewModel(Ticket Ticket)
    {
        _ticket = Ticket;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _ticket.Title;
        }
    }

    public List<Comment> Comments
    {
        get
        {
            return _ticket.Comments;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I create a new ViewModel with the Ticket Domain Model but the main concern that i have is returning a List of Domain Model Comments as i only want them to be read only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are at all concerned, don't expose your entity model (https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/03/Why-You-Never-Expose-Your-Domain-Model-As-Your-MVC-Model/). The link from Scott Allen also explains why. You can really mitigate the redundancy with a tool like automapper (https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/).

Comment: Steve Fenton's argument is that exposing your model to a browser in MVC presents an obvious security risk. That doesn't apply to a WPF/MVVM app.

Comment: Thank you for all of your replies. What I can get from this is I was corrent in thinking exposing the domain model is a bad idea and can be edited. I think the approach I'm going to take is creating strolgly typesld ViewModels that way I can control what is given to the user and also what can be get and set. I also think I will use ViewModels within ViewModels so a kind of parenting system to really control everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the [ReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx), and the method [AsReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx) provided by List.

Your comment property can be rewritten as -

```
public List<Comment> Comments
{
    get
    {
        return _ticket.Comments.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it would go against standards to put a ViewModel in a ViewModel so create a TicketViewModel and have a List of CommentViewModels?

Comment: can you better explain your intent of the list?

Comment: So the main ViewModel would be TicketViewModel that would be the Parent, and then i would have a List of CommentViewModels (Created by the Comment Domain Model) as a Child of the Parent model so then i can specify only the things that i want to get and set?

Comment: rule of thumb: as long as you have justification for it's presence in a strongly typed view. Nesting view models can be seen an ideal oop approach to define a view many will argue however.

Answer (score 1):

**For security:**

If i get what you are asking about then 
First of all the user can edit everything on the client side and we cannot do anything for this.
But for your concern if you have not added code on server side than no one will be able to change your data using your application , also you can add validation on server side.

**For adding List in a ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel
{

public string Title{get;set;}

public List<Comment> ListComments {get;}
}
```

*"i have is returning a List of Domain Model Comments as i only want them to be read only"*

you can use this,

```
public List<Comment> Comments { get; }
```

Comment: yes the list property can no longer be assigned however all the elements of the list can be modified, removed and added to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want something to be editable, just don't modify it.. I think this is unrelated to MVC.. You are in control of server code, so if you want comments to be readonly, just don't modify them in your server code. All these "models" exist as long as your HTML is being rendered on the server.

Client by itself won't be able to modify your database, only to modify it's HTML or send requests to your server.. It's your server code that actually modifies things.

Comment: I dont know if i explained myself well. I've heard and seen that you can send the server HTTP Posts with the extra fields that are not shown in the Razor HTML page but are still hidden in the HTML of the page. This is what im referring to http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Yes, user can send over http whatever he wants.. You can just ignore everything but what you need. Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, and not knowing the context it is in, I would suggest using the domain model itself in your view and not wrapping it in the TicketViewModel. The ViewModel doesn't seem to add anything.

For the read only comments: I don't think it matters whether the collection in the ViewModel is editable. What matters is that you don't render editable controls in your view. And most important that the code in your Save (or whatever it is called) action ignores whatever comments are posted.